# The break point in c++/WinRT Component code is not triggered

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, windows-runtime

I am trying to migrate a macOS app to UWP

there are some c++ code need to be reused, I put them in a WinRT/c++ component.

[image]

then I add it to the assembly reference of the UWP app and set it to mixed debug type.
I set the breakpoint in the c++/WinRT component code and rebuild the project.

Lately, I open the UWP app and build/run and call the WinRT/C++ component, everything is ok except the breakpoint in c++ code is not triggered

[image]

your comment welcome

----------------------------------updated question(Oct 5, 2020)

I try to create a simple component and add to a blank c# app
it works and calls the component correctly.
but still can not trigger the breakpoint in WinRT/c++ code

[image]

[image]

[image]

----------------------------------updated question(Oct 4, 2020)

**c++/WinRT Component**

[image]

**c# app**

[image]

----------------------------------updated question(Oct 3, 2020)
WinRT/C++ component code breakpoint

[image]

a new project simply call the WinRT/C++ component

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: Hello Arachide, make sure you are running in debug mode and Visual studio, you can disable breakpoint trigger off, make sure that in Build you let Visual studio output.

https://ibb.co/FWwHXZq

Comment: yes I am in debug mode and can set/remove the breakpoint

Comment: yes I am in debug mode and can set/remove the breakpoint in c++/WinRT code, but still can not trigger them

Comment: Hello Arachide,
can you please share a screenshot for both Debug and Build in solution?

Comment: If you want to trigger a break point in your C++/WinRT Componnet, the component project should be in the same solution as the UWP app. Then set the debugger type as Mixed(Managed and Native).

Comment: @ YanGu - MSFT  thanks it works! so now I add the WinRT component in two way(as a reference and as a project) do I need to do something (remove the WinRT project from c# app project) before compile and pack the app）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer from @YanGu - MSFT

> If you want to trigger a break point in your C++/WinRT Component, the
> component project should be in the same solution as the UWP app. Then
> set the debugger type as Mixed(Managed and Native)

Answer (score 1):

After I searched and tested I come into these ideas and solutions, first thing first, start from the simplest one.

Please make sure that you didn't disabled that breakpoint by yourself, you can do that with both keyboard shortcut Ctrl + F9 or right-click on any breakpoint and click disable the breakpoint.

[image]

You can use compile your solution using the -g command argument or tag, you can find that in solution properties, debugging.

[image]

The last one is changing the debugger type you can switch it from Mixed to Mixed (Managed and Native), Managed only or Native only or vice-versa.

I will search and test more for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I set the debug type to managed/native/mixed one by one, only can trigger breakpoint in managed type

Comment: I try all items you mentioned, still can not trigger breakpoint on native or mixed type (please refer to the updated question screenshot) in the c# app project

Comment: Hello Arachide, Please give me some time I will figure out why it happening.